# how to add ip address to cloud sql acsess list provide access on Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I tried

```
gcloud sql instances patch YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME --authorized-networks my-ip
```

but this command removes all the IP addresses from access-control list and add only mine. How can I add my ip address keeping previous IP addresses as well?

Comment: I have the same problem. Filed b/70747144.

Comment: This has proper documentation from Google nowadays: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add ip addresses via the console web interface

[console.developers.google.com](http://console.developers.google.com)

Go to Storage -> Cloud SQL-> Choose your instance -> Access Control -> Click "Add Item" where it shows Allowed Networks

Answer (score 5):

As James mentioned, it can easily be done using the Developers Console. Using the command line is doable albeit a little tricky. Searching through the ['Cloud SDK'](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/) reveals there seems to be no way of simply retrieving authorized networks.

You can however use the [`describe`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/instances/describe) command which will return all the settings of the Cloud SQL instance. From here, some rather brittle series of commands can be used to obtain what you're looking for. Here goes:

First, Get the full Cloud SQL instance description:

```
gcloud sql instances describe <instance-name>
```

Second, pipe results through `grep` to retrieve IP addresses of authorized networks which show up after `-`. Other IP address regular expressions can be found elsewhere if you prefer.

```
| grep -E "\-\s[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+"
```

Third, pipe results through `cut` to split each line on `-` and keep the latter half.

```
| cut -d '-' -f 2
```

Fourth, pipe results through `cut` again to split each line on empty space to remove the first blank space

```
| cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

Then, pipe results through `tr` to replace new lines with commas

```
| tr '\n' ','
```

Lastly, pipe results through `head` to remove trailing comma

```
| head -c -1
```

Your resulting command should like this:

```
gcloud sql instances describe <instance-name> | grep -E "\-\s[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+" | cut -d '-' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | tr '\n' ',' | head -c -1
```

This is a very brittle workaround. In addition, it exposes the certificate key and the particular regex above does not match IPv6 addresses or match subnets using the CDR notation. This simple operation definitely warrants a feature request. I strongly recommend filing one on the [Google App Engine public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list).

Answer (score 2):

Full flow (using **Nicholas** answer):

```
    # get zone from global meta data
    zone_full=`curl http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/zone -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"`
    zone=${zone_full##*/}

    # get sql-instance from metadata
    sql_instance=`curl http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/sql-instance -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"`

    # get current instance external natIP
    instance_nat_ip=`gcloud --format="value(networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP)" compute instances describe $HOSTNAME --zone=$zone`

    # get already authorized ips
    authorized_sql_ips=`gcloud sql instances describe $sql_instance | grep -E "\-\s[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+" | cut -d '-' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | tr '\n' ',' | head -c -1`

    # add instance's natIP to authorized SQL networks
    gcloud sql instances patch $sql_instance --authorized-networks $authorized_sql_ips,$instance_nat_ip
```